# Can't build JMC from source

Tags: java, maven, jfr, jmc

I need to use JMC to read some JFR files. I've tried to download zip's with compiled projects from Oracle and Azul, but it's not work for me. So I decide to build JMC from the source code.
I've download source from [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jmc).

When I clone project I have these errors:
[errors in InteliJ IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra6bA.png)

And when I'm trying to build (using command mvn p2:site) next error is occured:

```
[INFO] --- p2-maven-plugin:2.0.0:site (default-cli) @ external-dependencies ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.reficio.p2.P2Mojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.reficio.p2.P2Mojo not present
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/reficio/p2/P2Mojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass (SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass (URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100 (URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf (ClassRealm.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass (URLClassSpace.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load (NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  56.215 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-17T15:08:47+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin:2.0.0:site (default-cli) on project external-dependencies: Execution default-cli of goal org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin:2.0.0:site failed: Unable to load the mojo 'site' in the plugin 'org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin:2.0.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/reficio/p2/P2Mojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.reficio:p2-maven-plugin:2.0.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/reficio/p2-maven-plugin/2.0.0/p2-maven-plugin-2.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.4/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.1.0/aether-util-1.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/biz/aQute/bnd/biz.aQute.bndlib/5.3.0/biz.aQute.bndlib-5.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/2.3.1/mojo-executor-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/5.1.2/maven-bundle-plugin-5.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/osgi/org.osgi.service.log/1.5.0/org.osgi.service.log-1.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-core/2.5.0/tycho-core-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.6.3/maven-builder-support-3.6.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-util/1.4.1/maven-resolver-util-1.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.shared/2.5.0/org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.shared-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.shared/2.5.0/org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.shared-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/4.2.2/plexus-archiver-4.2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/3.2.0/plexus-io-3.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.4/snappy-0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.8/xz-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-cipher/2.0/plexus-cipher-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/sisu-equinox-embedder/2.5.0/sisu-equinox-embedder-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.osgi/3.17.100/org.eclipse.osgi-3.17.100.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-metadata-model/2.5.0/tycho-metadata-model-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/de/pdark/decentxml/1.4/decentxml-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-embedder-api/2.5.0/tycho-embedder-api-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.embedder.shared/2.5.0/org.eclipse.tycho.embedder.shared-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared/2.5.0/org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.25/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/sisu-equinox-launching/2.5.0/sisu-equinox-launching-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/sisu-equinox-api/2.5.0/sisu-equinox-api-2.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/lexst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/3.0.9/groovy-3.0.9.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
```

What should I install(or download) to solve this problem?

Comment: Why doesn’t it work for you? The effort there is probably much smaller than what you are doing now.

Comment: FWIW. The JDK comes with an API to read JFR files.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/consumer/RecordingFile.html

Comment: I need to analyze a lot of information in these jfr files, so this method is not suitable for me

Comment: it does not work due to a large number of errors in the logs. I could not find ready-made solutions, so I decided that it would be easier if I was in familiar conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
The main problem was that a had both versions of JDK (8 and 11), and I forget I've changed JAVA_HOME to JDK 8 few days ago, so JMC just couldn't find jdk.jfr (it's included only in 9 or later).
Moreover when you build JMC it's important to turn off VPN or configure specific parameters in .m2 directory, because JMC builder use jetty server and it can't work when VPN is working.